# TestContext.CurrentContext.Test is null on fixture setup

Tags: c#, nunit

while using nunit with R#, i want to use the `Property` in the `TestContext` in the `TestFixtureSetUp` and i get a null exception.
can't i use `TestContext`in the `TestFixtureSetUp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you be able to use it in the Test **Fixture** SetUp?  This is a method run once per test fixture, not specific to a given test so what would be the meaningful TestContext?

You can use it within a TestSetUp method (which runs before each test) e.g.:

```
[SetUp]
public void TestSetup()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Setting up the test: {0}", TestContext.TestName);
}
```

Just to clarify, the code executes:
1. TestFixtureSetUp  (no specific test context)
2. TestSetup - Test1 - TestTearDown
3. TestSetup - Test2 - TestTearDown
4. TestSetup - Test3 - TestTearDown
etc
n. TestFixtureTearDown (no specific test context)

Comment: i would like to use the Property if to activate a `Host` for a service and i would like to do this once and not before each test

Comment: Using a TestFixtureSetUp is good practice if all the tests within the same fixture require that setup - because it only gets run once (tests that don't require code in the TestFixtureSetUp ought to be in a different fixture usually).  My point is that the error you're getting *and* the name "TestContext" suggest that the TestContext class is relevant only once you're running an individual test (which includes its setup and teardown) but doesn't include the fixture-level methods

Comment: So if you want to activate a Host for a service, the TestFixtureSetUp sounds like the right place to do it but that's probably separate to TestContext - instead, just have a variable defined at the fixture type level